# Create executable JAR in Cucumber/Java project in Intellij/idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, pom.xml, executable-jar

I need to create an executable JAR for my Javabased Cucumber project.

This is my folder structure:

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/229x373q90/674/EiXWux.png

(The Bellyclass in main/java/skeleton is also not used). All the feature steps are in the resources/skeleton folder and all **step definitions** are under **test/java/skeleton**

the files that are not displayed are:
- gitignore, build.xml, cucumber-java-skeleton.iml, pom.xml and README.md

I've tried to do some research, but struggled finding out what I should include in my pom.xml file. I have currently ran my project using Intellij, but I need to hand it over to someone that can easily run the project on iOS/Mac.

Best regards, V.

Answer (score 1):

I could not see your structure , but as per my experience you can follow below structure to generate jar.

Suppose we are using maven we can have **"src/main/java"** like structure.

1:- Create main class and inside that use below code

- String[] arguments = {"--glue", "path/to/glue/code","--glue",
  "Second/Path/to/glue code", "--tags","@test",
             path,"--plugin","pretty","--plugin","json:/path/to/report"};
         cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(arguments);

Add below plugin in pom.xml to create runnable jar with dependency:-

```
<plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <phase>package</phase>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>single</goal>
                                   </goals>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <archive>
                                           <manifest>
                                               <mainClass>
                                                   com.cucumber.CucumberMain
                                               </mainClass>
                                           </manifest>
                                       </archive>
                                       <descriptorRefs>
                                           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                       </descriptorRefs>
                                   </configuration>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>
                       </plugin>
```

After this just build your code using mvn clean install and run the jar using java -jar "path and name of jar". It would work.

**Note:-**
Inside cucumber main, after performing task ,it calls system.exit(..), hence you can not do anything in you code after calling it until you use shutdownhook.

Comment: Hi, can you paste the sample code for CucumberMain class? I didn't understand exactly where to place it.